# How to update mobile app UI(android and iOS) when web UI is changed

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, architecture

I had a requirement in our company by senior management.We are working on a business app that can create,initialise and submit a process.This is both for web and mobile.Below is the flow of the app.

> - User logins in to the app.
> - Creates a process(a process is a form) by using a drag and drop UI.
> - Created process is initialised and submitted for approval.

Above is the flow of the application.Now,the requirement for mobile is,once the process is created in web that has to be dynamically updated in the mobile app.

What will be the better approach for this kind of requirements.

**Note:**Please don't get confused with the term process.Creation of process is some thing like leave request process,HR processes etc which are just normal forms.

Technically speaking,need solution for a form customisation using a drag and drop that has to be updated in mobile dynamically when changes are made in web.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you want to do is keep a process in sync between the web and your app.

You have two choices. You can either make a call to your API every x seconds and check if there are any changes. The other way would be to use WebSockets which allow you to push data from the server to the client instantly. (So you when there is a change you can notify the app and update immediately).

Both ways have advantages and disadvantages, especially when scaling your app. If you want to have a "real-time" feeling in our app, I would recommend using WebSockets.

Comment: Dear Andreas,Thanks for your response.Your understanding is correct.But to make it more clear and specific,there is a web dashboard with a form builder(drag&drop form elements) including tables.Once a form is created and saved,the saved form has to be shown in mobile app.I am actually looking for a way to sync the saved form  in mobile dynamically with out creating/changing the layouts in mobile.I am not sure about possibilities at this moment.Example:https://bootsnipp.com/forms

Comment: Do you want to sync the form content or the form layout? To me it sounds like you have 2 separate problems. You first need to find a way to programmatically change the layout and/or content of the form on mobile (using angular/ionic). When you figure out how to do that, you can then solve the problem of how you get the changes from the web UI to the mobile app (using the methods I described above).

Comment: I want to sync form layout first.For now we are trying to pull all js and dependency files of the form from the server(Using angular) and customising according to mobile UI. I don't know how feasible it is.But looking for better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a progressive web app and try out the ionic cloud services
https://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/

Live deployments let you publish web assets such as HTML, JS, and CSS directly to your users without going through the app store.

This lets you:

Update your application on demand.
Get new features and bug fixes to your users quickly.

But it has a price associated with it but!